# Use matrix values in secret

Tags: github-actions

Using GitHub Actions I need to use a different secret according to a matrix value:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        projects: ['Api', 'Web']

    steps:
      - name: Download
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: ${{ matrix.projects }}
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}

      - name: Publish
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ matrix.projects }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PROFILE_??? }}
          package: ${{ github.workspace }}/${{ matrix.projects }}.nupkg
```

Each project has a different secret name saved in the GitHub repository:

In my repository I added 2 secrets:

```
AZURE_PROFILE_Api
AZURE_PROFILE_Web
```

So the secret name is:

```
AZURE_PROFILE + ${{ matrix.projects }}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Or you could have two environments with the _same_ secret name, which would also allow you to reduce the scope of access.